# How to write a simple server socket, and simple client socket in python3?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, network-programming, server

The title basically says it all. I want the absolute, most barebones, simplest implementation of a server socket, and a client socket. Im sure there are questions similar to this, but I have not found anything that works for me.  If possible, please have the server socket send the message "hi" to the client socket which receives this and prints it out. Vice-versa would also be nice just so I can see a client sending to a server and how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Why was this post downvoted? This is well within the field of allowed questions of the site. Its specific, its too the point. Yes, it does have alot of room for use interpretation and variation is programming method but the end goal is specifically defined and a nonspecific procedure is as well. For the person who downvoted my post, and the two answers, I'd like to understand why. Thanks...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The documentation has pretty much what you're asking for: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example

Comment: Ahh, thats what I was looking for. I checked the documentation earlier however and I couldn't find it. I guess I need to start looking harder... Thanks so much, sorry I should have found that on my own.

Answer (score 0):

besides [Doc of Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html), [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm) is also a good place to start learning

Comment: Thank you! That also helps, again, I should have found this on my own. I used tutorialspoint a bit for when I was learning java. I really need to work on my research skills. Next time I'll google more before I ask questions here!